# Did Bard ride the cart in the novel?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, adaptation-comparison, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In *The Battle of The Five Armies*, during Azog's attack on the city, Bard's children are about to be crushed by a troll (I think it's a troll, or maybe an ogre).

Bard, seeing this, grabs a nearby wagon and rides it down a path towards the troll, jumps the wagon over his children, collides with the troll, flies through the air with the troll and lands on top of the troll while simultaneously stabbing it in the heart.

Did this scene take place in the novel, or was it added for the movie?

Comment: Basic rule: Peter Jackson made up *a ton* of stuff to get his Hobbit movies up to three separate releases and you really don't have any idea what is in the book unless you read the book. It's a short book, so there is no excuse (and no reason to try to stretch it to three movies for that matter).

Comment: There is, of course, a reason to stretch it to 3 movies: "The Search for More Money".

Comment: I don't understand why Peter Jackson gets so much hate for making three movies out of this book. I would be absolutely and totally happy to have 6 Hobbit movies. And i would gladly pay for those. Maybe i'm just a stupid consumer. Or maybe i just love Hobbit \ LOTR in particular and movies in general. (sorry for the rant).

Comment: I hate the 3 movies because I love the Hobbit. The movies took a bunch of Tolkien's writing (which is a classic for a reason) and replaced it with bad writing. So it's not the Hobbit anymore. It's a bad rewriting/whole new thing. If it had taken 6 movies to tell a good story reasonably close to the book, I would have loved it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## No

In fact, the goblins don't even attack the town, so...

The 'Battle of Five Armies' in the novel is when the goblins and Wargs attack the mountain where Thorin & co are holding fort, which the elves, dwarves, and humans (and me and Beorn) on one side, and the goblins and Wargs on the other.

The only time that Laketown is attacked is when the dragon comes (and destroys it).

Comment: By "the village" do you mean lake town? Or "Dale" the location where the scene happened in the Movie?

Comment: Lake-town (Esgaroth?) not "the village" to be strictly correct with the book.

Comment: me? ohhh... in character answer

Comment: I'm confused. If you are Mithrandir, why do you look like Sauron?

Comment: @Oriol plot twist...

Comment: Peter Jackson should have added that to the Hobbit.